# Why didn't Palpatine change his plans after Amidala's escape?

Tags: star-wars, darth-sidious, the-phantom-menace

My understanding of Palpatine's plan for the Phantom Menace was to have the Trade Federation force Amidala to make the invasion legal, so he could complain in the Senate and get a vote of no confidence that would put him in power.

But since Amidala could instigate the vote, (and probably better as a 14 year old girl in emotional distress will garner more sympathy than a 80 year old politician) why did he use her escape to his advantage? He could have had her instigate the vote and not risk Maul by making him bring here back to Amidala.

Why did he make a choice to prolong his plan rather than adapt, and in the process risk his apprentice and their secrecy to their oldest enemies?

Answer (score 2):

He didn't just need to win a single vote. He needed to get planet leaders and powerful politicians to support a greater centralization into a galactic empire.

The ideal would have been Padme signing a treaty (aided by Maul), giving her planet to the Trade Federation to be abused and tortured. An extended period of this would give him increasing power and let him take moves like seizing the banks and other aspects of centralization as he did in the Clone Wars cartoons.

Instead, the Trade Federation was quickly defeated. Sidious as such needed to set up a new leader, Count Dooku, and prepare a new more competent Trade Federation style antagonist, the Separatists, as an enemy ten years later for Attack of the Clones. Sidious gained extra power thanks to Padme's vote, but they didn't gain the continual sense of emergency that they wanted in the Phantom Menace thanks to the meddlesome activities of the Jedi.

Comment: This answers my question in no way.

Comment: You were assuming his plan was to use her to force a vote to give him power. That was an aspect, but not all of his plan. He needed a constant state of emergency to get what he wanted, not a vote.